# union of two table - intersection of two table

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have following tables;

```
 A   B                       A   B
 _____                       _____
 1   t                       7   a
 2   r                       5   d
 3   e                       3   e
 4   f                       9   a
 5   d                       10  c
 6   s                       11  a
 7   a
```

And, output should be ;

```
 A   B                     
 _____                     
 1   t                      
 2   r                     

 4   f

 6   s

 9   a
 10  c
 11  a
```

In other words I want really different thing. I can only tell with  [this figure](http://www.budaconsulting.com/Portals/52677/images/venn.png), take a look at. I want (A union B).
How can I do that ?

Comment: Do the union (all), group and filter count > 1

Comment: What you want is the *complement* of A union B, or the intersection of the complement of A with the complement of B (De Morgan's Law). Also,  the question would be clearer if you label your columns differently from your tables (both are A and B).

Comment: Also, your diagram doesn't really clarify what you want as C != the expected output described in the question.

Comment: A.k.a. [symmetric difference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference), "the union without the intersection."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This query will do it.  It loads up all the records from both tables, then displays all those that exist once

```
SELECT
  A, B
FROM
  (SELECT A, B FROM TABLE1
   UNION ALL
   SELECT A, B FROM TABLE2)
  AS COMBINED
GROUP BY
  A, B
HAVING
    COUNT(*) = 1
ORDER BY A;
```

Comment: just noticed.  thats exactly what  Andrzej Nosal said

Comment: Gary, I am trying to simply load up all records from all columns in two small tables for a SQLite query in Android Studio.  But I'm struggling with syntax.  Do you know what I'm doing wrong here?      String select = "SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM " + TOTALCOUNT + " UNION ALL SELECT * FROM " + USERINPUTS) + " AS COMBINED";

Comment: @AJW  Probably best if you raise that as a separate question so its not just me looking at it.  I have no experience of Android Studio

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT f.A, f.B
FROM firstTable f
LEFT JOIN secondTable s ON (f.A = s.A)
WHERE (s.A IS NULL)
UNION
SELECT s.A, s.B
FROM firstTable f
RIGHT JOIN secondTable s ON (f.A = s.A)
WHERE (f.A IS NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT iResult.* 
FROM
    (SELECT A, B
    FROM tableA
    WHERE A NOT IN
        (SELECT Distinct A FROM tableB)
    UNION
    SELECT A, B
    FROM tableB
    WHERE A NOT IN
        (SELECT Distinct A FROM tableB)) as iResult
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT A, B
FROM Table1

UNION

SELECT A, B
FROM Table2

EXCEPT

SELECT t1.A, t1.B
FROM Table1 t1
  INNER JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.A = t2.A AND t1.B = t2.B
```

Comment: This is elegant, although it's worth noting MySQL still doesn't support EXCEPT*, even though it's standard SQL 92. *As of version 5.0.13

Comment: @TimGee: I think you must be right. Still, the question is tagged `sqlite` at the moment. :)

Comment: Can replace the last part (inner join) with `SELECT A, B FROM Table1 INTERSECT SELECT A, B FROM Table2` and add parens for clarity and safety because the precedence for `INTERSECT`, `EXCEPT` and `UNION` is implementation dependent.

Comment: @onedaywhen: Absolutely. I was just trying to avoid a four-part query (`A union B except (C intersect D)`, even though A = C and B = D), because that would make the resulting query hardly ever better than `(A except B) union (C except D)`, which seemed too obvious and boring. So this is my attempt at cheating into ‘fewer’ selects (apparently). :)

Answer (score 0):

**Edit** Removed prior "solution" since I realised it's the same as the one proposed by Gary.

```
(select a, b from table_1 minus 
 select a, b from table_2)       union
(select a, b from table_2 minus 
 select a, b from table_1);
```

This seemed to work with the followoing data on Oracle:

```
create table table_1 (
  a number,
  b varchar(2)
);

create table table_2 (
  a number,
  b varchar(2)
);


insert into table_1 values  (1  ,'t');
insert into table_1 values  (2  ,'r');
insert into table_1 values  (3  ,'e');
insert into table_1 values  (4  ,'f');
insert into table_1 values  (5  ,'d');
insert into table_1 values  (6  ,'s');
insert into table_1 values  (7  ,'a');

insert into table_2 values  (7  ,'a');
insert into table_2 values  (5  ,'d');
insert into table_2 values  (3  ,'e');
insert into table_2 values  (9  ,'a');
insert into table_2 values  (10 ,'c');
insert into table_2 values  (11 ,'a');
```

Comment: I don't think MINUS is SQL standard, although I suspect all you need to do is change it to EXCEPT for better compatibility. Even so, MySQL doesn't support EXCEPT.

Answer (score -1):

Simply

```
SELECT a, b FROM table1 UNION SELECT a, b FROM table2;
```

Comment: While technically this is the correct answer to (A union B) it should be apparent from reading the rest of the question that this is not what the questioner requires.